# Vertical text not appearing

Tags: css

I have a table with a vertical text but I’m not familiar to text-transform and I can’t make my page to display it.

Here’s my css:

```
table.alt tr td.verticalText {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 20% 40%;

    height: auto;
    width: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/393736/

When I test it with jsfiddle or codepen, I have no problem. But when I test it with my browser, the text isn’t displayed.

How can I fix this?

Edit:
Here's an extented html: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/393777/
And css: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/393780/

Comment: What a amazing, I think it's about your native browser rather than the code.

Comment: Open your *console* and see for **errors** you have `http://sudrap.org/paste/static/base.css/reset.css/`. so remove the **last slash**

Comment: @Praveen, I couldn't understand you.

Comment: Your css file is not loaded in your html(404 error)

Comment: @ToddMark I tested it with Chrome and Firefox 32.0.3